flutter bloc delays to rebuild BlocConsumer after emit
I have noticed that the bloc/cubit delays to rebuild after emit to to a new state
for example in my code.
I expect for the bloc/cubit to change the state and refresh the blocConsumer with no delay.
What is the reasons for this?
Add Document Function In The Bloc/Cubit
    try {
      emit(AddDocumentLoading());

      AddDocumentModel? makeDocumentReadyFunctionResult = await makeDocumentReadyToUpload(context, formKey: formKey, documentNumber: documentNumber, documentExpiryDate: documentExpiryDate, documentNotes: documentNotes, remark: remarks);
      emit(AddDocumentSuccess());

    
    } catch (e) {
      emit(AddDocumentFailure(message: e.toString()));
      return false;
    }
  }    

My BlocConsumer Code
    BlocBuilder<AddDocumentCubit, AddDocumentState>(
                      builder: (context, state) {
                          return CustomButton(
                            onPressed: () async{
                               bool isSuccess = await AddDocumentCubit.get(context).addDocument(
                                  context, formKey: _formKey,
                                  remarks: _documentRemarksFieldController.text,
                                  documentNotes: _documentNotesFieldController.text,
                                  documentNumber: _documentNumberFieldController.text,
                                  documentExpiryDate: _documentExpiryDateFieldController.text
                               );
                               if(isSuccess) {
                                 setState(() {
                                   resetForm();
                                   isSubmitted = true;
                                 });
                               }


                            },

                            isLoading: (state is AddDocumentLoading) ? true : false ,
                            text: S.of(context).SaveDocument , isFullWidth: true,);
                        }
                    )

So, here when I press the button, it lags for a second after the Bloc/Cubit emits to a new state and after the lag it rebuild the BlocConsumer/Blocbuilder/BlocListner. I have no idea why this happens, but what is the reason for this? And how can I prevent it from happening?

There are multiple issues with your code, with the usage of Bloc. But to answer your question, it might be stuck at the line

bool isSuccess = await AddDocumentCubit.get(context).addDocument(...

as it is awaiting the execution of addDocument Method.
You may use a BlocConsumer like below. And avoid calling setState by driving everything through the bloc if possible.
BlocConsumer<BlocA, BlocAState>(
  listener: (context, state) {
    // Reset your form based on the state whether success or failure
  },
  builder: (context, state) {
    // your builder here
  },
);

As a quick non recommended fix, you can try this
CustomButton(
            onPressed: () {
              AddDocumentCubit.get(context).addDocument(
                  context, formKey: _formKey,
                  remarks: _documentRemarksFieldController.text,
                  documentNotes: _documentNotesFieldController.text,
                  documentNumber: _documentNumberFieldController.text,
                  documentExpiryDate: _documentExpiryDateFieldController.text
              ).then((isSuccess) {
                if(isSuccess) {
                  setState(() {
                    resetForm();
                    isSubmitted = true;
                  });
                }
              })
            },

